# Assert Intermediate Result in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dynamic-programming

This is the question.

> Define a predicate sigma(N,S) such that S = 1+2+...+N. And remember every **new** intermediate result in the query. For example, after query sigma(3,S), it will store some thing like sigma(2,3),sigma(3,6) to database such that we needn't do duplicate and useless work later.

I tried the following method to solve it.

```
sigmares(1,1).

mysigma(N,A,Sum) :-
    sigmares(N,SN),
    Sum is SN+A,
    !.

mysigma(N1,Acc,Sum) :-
    N is N1-1,
    A is Acc + N1,
    mysigma(N,A,Sum),
    assertz(sigmares(N1,Sum)). % <<<<<<<<<< This line doesn't work properly.

sigma(N,X) :-
    mysigma(N,0,X).
```

There is some problem with assertz line. Since sum can be only initialized once which is the value of sum from 1 to N, sigma(2,6),sigma(3,6) for query sigma(3,S) will be inserted. Is there any other way to store **new** intermediate sigmares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's good coding style to always declare the dynamic predicates that your code uses using the standard `dynamic/1` directive. Simply add at the beginning of the file:

```
:- dynamic(sigmares/2).
```

An interesting aspect of your definition of the `mysigma/3` predicate is that it is a non tail-recursive with the consequence that it requires space linear on its inputs. But that allows it to cache all intermediate results as you intend. A fixed version of your code will be:

```
:- dynamic(sigma_cache/2).

sigma_cache(1, 1).

sigma(N, S) :-
    sigma_cache(N, S),
    !.
sigma(N, S) :-
    N > 1,
    M is N - 1,
    sigma(M, SM),
    S is SM + N,
    assertz(sigma_cache(N, S)).
```

Sample call:

```
?- sigma(5, S).
S = 15.

?- listing(sigma_cache/2).
:- dynamic sigma_cache/2.

sigma_cache(1, 1).
sigma_cache(2, 3).
sigma_cache(3, 6).
sigma_cache(4, 10).
sigma_cache(5, 15).

true.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you only cache final computation result without intermediate result. What I want to store includes **new** intermediate sigmares.

Comment: Sorry for missing that detail. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps me. But I think functor `sigma_` and `sigma` are same and we need only one:D

Comment: Yes, of course. Remains from a previous answer. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This alternative answer provides a solution based on the *tabling* mechanism found in some Prolog systems, including B-Prolog, Ciao, SWI-Prolog, XSB, and YAP:

```
:- table(sigma/2).

sigma(1, 1).
sigma(N, S) :-
    N > 1,
    M is N - 1,
    sigma(M, SM),
    S is SM + N.
```

Let's test it with the help of SWI-Prolog handy `time/1` library predicate that reports the time and number of inferences taken to prove a goal:

```
?- time(sigma(5, S)).
% 166 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.006 seconds (2% CPU, 1238806 Lips)
S = 15.

?- time(sigma(5, S)).
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (68% CPU, 208333 Lips)
S = 15.
```

Note that I used a non tail-recursive definition for the `sigma/2` predicate on purpose so that all intermediate results are cached (as per the requirements in your question). For example:

```
?- time(sigma(4, S)).
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (70% CPU, 217391 Lips)
S = 10.
```

You can see that, after the first call, the result is cached by the tabling mechanism, resulting in a much lower number of inferences when we repeat the query.

```
?- time(sigma(6, S)).
% 32 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (86% CPU, 727273 Lips)
S = 21.

?- time(sigma(6, S)).
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (70% CPU, 217391 Lips)
S = 21.
```

Note again the number of inferences. The first query reuses the cached result for `sigma(5, S)` and caches the result for `sigma(6, S)`, making the repeated query again faster as it just reuses the cached result.